HCI_LE_Set_Host_Channel_Classification, where and how to find the corresponding API to use in Mobile APP
HCI_LE_Set_Host_Channel_Classification can be used to set channel map from a BLE Master to a BLE Peripheral.
import android.bluetooth.le.*, this is the library I used to make the mobile APP
Now our BLE 4.2 Hardware needs to update the channel map because of congestion which leads to disconnect. I am not able to find a way to use this in android
I was expecting there to be an API which will help me do this. I am not able to find that. I am looking for guidance on if the API is there and if there, how can we use

Android doesn't allow for sending HCI commands directly. A subset of them is wrapped in a high-level API which can be used, but that's all.
Controlling channel map is not possible from Android application.
